# Executing multiple exes in powershell

Tags: powershell, exe

In my powershell script file, I would like to invoke two executables (and two exes don't terminate). How do I do it? Can I just do

```
C:\App.exe
C:\App2.exe
```

or will the first line (C:\App.exe) block the second line (C:\App2.exe) from executing since App.exe doesn't terminate?

Comment: `Start "" "c:\App.exe"` and `Start "" "c:\App2.exe"`

Comment: Are these GUI or console apps? In the latter case, do you need to show or capture their output?

Comment: `Start` is an alias for `Start-Process`. Do not put aliases into script files.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `Start-Process` cmdlet

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\App.exe"
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\App2.exe"
```

This will start the program `C:\App.exe` and will start the `C:\App2.exe` immediately after, without waiting for the process to terminate.

See [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: While this will result in _asynchronous_ execution, it is important to note that (a) _on Windows_ each executable will launch in a _new console window_ and (b) that _on Unix_, where execution in a separate window is fundamentally unsupported, this is only appropriate for applications that do not produce output.